# MVC4 Conditional HTML using Razor and spaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I am using the Bootstrap CSS in conjunction with MVC4 and I am having a small issue i can't seem to figure out.

I use this in my code

```
 @(Model.Enabled ? "class=btn btn-primary" : "class=btn")
```

The actual html that renders is

```
class="btn" btn-primary
```

How I want into it to render like so

```
class="btn btn-primary"
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it figured out with the help of a co-worker

```
 class="@(Model.Enabled ? "btn btn-primary" : "btn")"
```

Will give the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You have no quotes in your string, so the `class` attribute only sees "btn". Try

```
@(Model.Enabled ? "class='btn btn-primary'" : "class='btn'")
```

or

```
@(Model.Enabled ? "class=\"btn btn-primary\"" : "class=\"btn\"")
```

Comment: That does not work, MVC will automatically add quotes in the rendered html. I actually just got it to work. Ill post the answer